# Apple Script to turn File Sharing off & on in one script

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-mountain-lion, file-sharing

I am pulling my hair out to write a script that does the following in 10.8. :

-uncheck 'File Sharing' in the 'Sharing' Controlpanel

-check 'File Sharing' in the 'Sharing' Controlpanel

-make sure that it is checked when the script finishes

Why I want to do this ? Because there is a bug in 10.8. with Samba (cannot smb-login from another machine), if File sharing gets turned off an back on when starting up, all is fine.

Can anyone help me out on this … ? Should be an easy one for you guys :-)

Thank you very much in advance, best- Ph!L!pp

Answer (score 1):

This code should toggle the sharing preferences, wait 1 second, then toggle them again.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
 activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
tell process "System Preferences"
click menu item "Sharing" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
delay 2
tell window "Sharing"
  click checkbox 1 of row 3 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1
  delay 1
  if (exists sheet 1) then
    if (exists button "Turn AirPort On" of sheet 1) then
      click button "Turn AirPort On" of sheet 1
      delay 1
    end if
    click button "Start" of sheet 1
  end if
end tell
end tell
end tell
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
tell process "System Preferences"
click menu item "Sharing" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
delay 2
tell window "Sharing"
  click checkbox 1 of row 3 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1
  delay 1
  if (exists sheet 1) then
    if (exists button "Turn AirPort On" of sheet 1) then
      click button "Turn AirPort On" of sheet 1
      delay 1
    end if
    click button "Start" of sheet 1
  end if
end tell
end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thanx, that was quick ! But does this also ensure that file sharing is on when the script finishes… ? Best-

Comment: I have edited the code, now it will toggle the preferences twice. This means that in order to have the file sharing on when the script finishes you will need it on before you run the script.

Comment: Thanks again ! I figured out that with delay 1 3 (..?) clicks are needed to toggle off & back on… anyway, got it to work now.thx again & best-

Comment: If the answer I gave you worked, please could you mark it as correct by clicking the tick mark

Comment: Hello again, unfortunately it's not working reliably… sometimes sharing is on after the script, sometimes not. Any ideas ? Best-

Comment: I've never heard of a script working sometimes and not other times before, are you sure you are remembering to turn the preferences on before running the script?